# Android : How to show the cursor when Button is clicked

Tags: android

I have the search view at the top of my layout I want when I( clicked the button the cursor should show in the search bar.
here is the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knssb.png)

Comment: `searchView.requestFocus()`?

Answer (score 0):

Create an ID for the SearchView and use this code to create actions within it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.beneficiary_search, menu);
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.searchicon);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
    searchView.requestFocus()
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
    }
```